# zero sized heap memory in page aligned allocation`

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, memory-mapping, virtual-address-space

I'm trying to study how Linux would behave if I were to allocate a 10 bytes of memory at every page boundary for a total of ten pages. Here is the program I could come up with:

```
  1 #include <stdlib.h>$
  2 #include <stdio.h>$
  3 #include <time.h>$
  4 #include <unistd.h>$
  5 #include <string.h>$
  6 $
  7 #define PAGESIZE getpagesize()$
  8 int main () {$
  9     int *ArrP[10] = {NULL};$
 10     int pgSz = PAGESIZE;$
 11     int randnum;$
 12 $
 13     
 14     for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(ArrP)/sizeof(int*)); i++) {$
 15         if(posix_memalign((void **)&ArrP[i], pgSz, 10)) {$
 16             perror("error getting page aligned mem: ");$
 17             exit(1);$
 18         }$
 19         else$
 20             printf("ArrP[%d] = %lu\n", i, ArrP[i]);$
 21     }$
 22 $
 23     srand(time(0));$
 24     while(1) {$
 25         for (int i = 0; i <(sizeof(ArrP)/sizeof(int*)); i++) {$
 26             randnum = rand();$
 27             memcpy(ArrP[i], &randnum, sizeof(int));$
 28         }$
 29     }$
 30     return 0;$
 31 }$
```

However when I run it, the /proc/pid/maps file shows a heap size of 0.
here's the content of that file:

```
555555554000-555555555000 r--p 00000000 08:01 1966744                    /home/AB1/ProgPractice/InternalFragmentation
555555555000-555555556000 r-xp 00001000 08:01 1966744                    /home/AB1/ProgPractice/InternalFragmentation
555555556000-555555557000 r--p 00002000 08:01 1966744                    /home/AB1/ProgPractice/InternalFragmentation
555555557000-555555558000 r--p 00002000 08:01 1966744                    /home/AB1/ProgPractice/InternalFragmentation
555555558000-555555559000 rw-p 00003000 08:01 1966744                    /home/AB1/ProgPractice/InternalFragmentation
555555559000-55555557a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [heap]
7ffff7dd8000-7ffff7dfd000 r--p 00000000 08:01 2234184                    /usr/lib/libc-2.30.so
7ffff7dfd000-7ffff7f4a000 r-xp 00025000 08:01 2234184                    /usr/lib/libc-2.30.so
7ffff7f4a000-7ffff7f94000 r--p 00172000 08:01 2234184                    /usr/lib/libc-2.30.so
7ffff7f94000-7ffff7f95000 ---p 001bc000 08:01 2234184                    /usr/lib/libc-2.30.so
7ffff7f95000-7ffff7f98000 r--p 001bc000 08:01 2234184                    /usr/lib/libc-2.30.so
7ffff7f98000-7ffff7f9b000 rw-p 001bf000 08:01 2234184                    /usr/lib/libc-2.30.so
7ffff7f9b000-7ffff7fa1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffff7fce000-7ffff7fd1000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7ffff7fd1000-7ffff7fd2000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
7ffff7fd2000-7ffff7fd4000 r--p 00000000 08:01 2234140                    /usr/lib/ld-2.30.so
7ffff7fd4000-7ffff7ff3000 r-xp 00002000 08:01 2234140                    /usr/lib/ld-2.30.so
7ffff7ff3000-7ffff7ffb000 r--p 00021000 08:01 2234140                    /usr/lib/ld-2.30.so
7ffff7ffc000-7ffff7ffd000 r--p 00029000 08:01 2234140                    /usr/lib/ld-2.30.so
7ffff7ffd000-7ffff7ffe000 rw-p 0002a000 08:01 2234140                    /usr/lib/ld-2.30.so
7ffff7ffe000-7ffff7fff000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffffffde000-7ffffffff000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 --xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
```

I've disabled ASLR but it doesn't make a difference. Any suggestions

Comment: When you post code, please post *valid* code.  Line numbers and those weird `$` characters at the end of every line are not characteristics of valid code.

Comment: `(void **)&ArrP[i]` is questionable.  It likely leads to a violation of the strict-aliasing rule.

Comment: `555555559000-55555557a000` is not zero size.

Comment: `%lu` is not the proper format string to print a pointer.  The proper format string is `%p`, but you have to cast the pointer to `void *` to be fully conformant.

Comment: Oh ok. My bad. I confused the offset with size

Comment: @JohnBollinger could you elaborate on what you mean in your second comment?

Comment: You misunderstand what `/proc/pid/maps` is telling you.  To get the *RAM* size of a `/proc/pid/maps` entry you have to take the difference of the first two numbers on the line; the number in the sixth column is only meaningful for file maps, not "anonymous" memory allocations.  Also, the "heap" allocation is the one controlled by the `sbrk` system call; `posix_memalign` may call `mmap` instead. (You can check this with `strace`.  The entry at `7ffff7f9b000-7ffff7fa1000` appears to be RAM allocated with `mmap`.)

Comment: Also also, almost all C library functions are allowed to make internal calls to `malloc` for scratch storage, so not all of the space in the heap(s) necessarily belongs to allocations made directly by your program.

Comment: @zwol how do I use strace in a program

Comment: @HighOnMeat, it is allowed to convert an object pointer to a different object-pointer type, as the expression I called out does, but in many cases it produces undefined behavior to access the pointed-to object through the converted pointer.  `posix_memalign()` will produce exactly such undefined behavior when it writes the address of the allocated memory through the pointer you provide as its first argument, because `void *` and `int *` are not compatible types.  In practice, the UB is likely to take the form of the behavior you are expecting anyway, but it is not safe to rely on that.

Comment: @JohnBollinger but that is what ‘posix_memalign’ expects doesn’t it? Which is why I did that. Most examples of this do it exactly like that

Comment: @HighOnMeat, the problem is the type mismatch.  `posix_memalign()` expects a pointer to a `void *`.  Cast notwithstanding, the thing that actually resides where the pointer you pass points is an `int *`. These are not the same thing, and accessing an object of one of these types as if it had the other type produces undefined behavior.  This is so *even if these two type have the same size and representation*, as they will on all POSIX-conforming systems.  Again, the manifestation of the UB is fairly likely to be what you expected anyway, but that just makes the issue more insidious.

Comment: @JohnBollinger do you imply that if I cast it that way (void **) to satisfy the compiler, it might result in undefined behavior with the memory?

Comment: @HighOnMeat, I mean that casting the original pointer is not the correct way to address the compiler diagnostic, and doing it *does* result in UB in your case.  The correct solution is to pass a pointer that really does point to a `void *`.  You could arrange for that by changing the element type of the array or by using a temporary.  Casts are rarely an appropriate solution to anything, and pretty much every cast has mild code smell.